# Restricting unitary irreducible representations of the Poincaré group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, unitary-representations

The Poincaré group is the isometry group of Minkowski spacetime and every point in Minkowski spacetime is stabilised by a subgroup of the Poincaré group isomorphic to the Lorentz group.  Let us fixed one such Lorentz subgroup.  It is convenient to consider the universal covering groups of both the Poincaré and Lorentz groups.

The unitary irreducible representations of the Poincaré group were famously constructed by Wigner in his 1939 paper in the Annals of Mathematics: [On unitary representations of the inhomogeneous Lorentz group](https://doi.org/10.2307/1968551).  The unitary irreducible representations of the Lorentz group are also famous: apart from the trivial representation, there are two series: the unitary principal series, labelled by an integer and a real number, and the complementary series indexed by a real number $0 < x < 2$.  They are described, for example, in Knapp's Representation theory of semisimple groups (Theorem 16.2).

A unitary irreducible representation of the Poincaré group restricts to a unitary representation of the Lorentz group, which is generally not irreducible.  My question is about the details of such restrictions.  Are the explicit restriction described somewhere?

Comment: My first thought was "Mackey theory", and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_imprimitivity#Applications_to_the_theory_of_group_representations) mentions the importance of the Poincaré group (= inhomogeneous Lorentz group) as an application, but gives no reference ….

Comment: Indeed, Wigner's construction is an example of Mackey's theory of induced representations.  Alas one does not induce the Poincaré unitary irreducible representations from a representation of the Lorentz group, but from the representation of the stabiliser of a character of the abelian ideal (the translations).

Comment: I've also wondered about this, never seen anything written about it. These irreps are very reducible under Lorentz.  Thinking about it starting with simpler examples, one can first ask about how an irrep of the 3d Euclidean group decomposes under SO(3). There in momentum space these are functions on a sphere, decompose as spherical harmonics.  In 2+1 d, some irreps of Poincare will be functions on hyperboloid, Spin(2,1)=SL(2,R) acts, that should be known.  In 3+1d, looking at SL(2,C) acting on functions on 3-d hyperboloids.

Comment: @PeterWoit  Yes, I expect the restriction should be a direct integrals of unitary reps of Lorentz, but I wanted to know the explicit form.  There is a theorem of Mackey's on restriction, but it is not easy for me to apply off the shelf.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested in this question since it's related to the celestial holography. There are some old physics-oriented papers discussing this restriction problem.

By "physics-oriented" I mean the style similar to Harish-Chandra's construction of the HC modules of the $4d$ Lorentz group in [Infinite irreducible representations of the Lorentz group](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1947.0047). Usually the aspects of convergence and completeness are not rigorous.

In ["Lorentz Basis" of the Poincare Group: I](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/9/8/1274/234423/Lorentz-Basis-of-the-Poincare-Group) and ["Lorentz Basis" of the Poincare Group: II](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/12/9/1822/223733/Lorentz-Basis-of-the-Poincare-Group-II), the authors constructed the intertwining maps that decompose massive/massless Wigner representations of the $4d$ Poincare group into unitary irreps of the Lorentz group, see particularly Equation (3.13) and Section 5 in ["Lorentz Basis" of the Poincare Group: I](https://pubs.aip.org/aip/jmp/article-abstract/9/8/1274/234423/Lorentz-Basis-of-the-Poincare-Group). I believe this is equivalent to the "conformal primary wavefunction" in the modern celestial holography literature.

There are some other related old papers collected in Appendix B of [2204.02505](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.02505) (the discrete series representations mentioned there are actually isomorphic to certain principal series.)